# React-query: how to paginate with useInfiniteQuery

Tags: reactjs

I would like to use react-query's `useInfiniteQuery`. Everything seems clear but the pagination, part.

The documentation exemple is:

```js
export default () => {
  const {
    status,
    data,
    error,
    isFetching,
    isFetchingMore,
    fetchMore,
    canFetchMore,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(
    'projects',
    async (key, nextId = 0) => {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/projects?cursor=' + nextId)
      return data
    },
    {
      getFetchMore: lastGroup => lastGroup.nextId,
    }
  )
```

I understand what it does. `projects` is the id of the query, used for the cache, and then there is the function, that performs an api call. Now what about the `nextId` variable? It starts at zero, so the backend will know it must only return results from 0 to x (can we also pass a dynamic limit by the way?). But when `fetchMore()` - the function to trig the query again - is called, how on earth does `useInfiniteQuery` knows it should increment `nextId`?

Answer (score 9):

I'm trying to make an infinite scroll with rick and morty API and here's how I implemented it:

Your function (`getCharacters`) should accept a `key` and a prop (`nextPage`) and returns an object that includes the data (`data`) from your fetch and the page identifier (`nextPage`) plus 1.

```js
const getCharacters = async (key, nextPage = 1) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/character/?page=${nextPage}`);
  const { results } = await res.json();
  return {
    data: results,
    nextPage: nextPage + 1,
  };
};

const { status, data, fetchMore } = useInfiniteQuery(
  ['characters'],
  getCharacters,
  {
    getFetchMore: (lastGroup, allGroups) => lastGroup.nextPage, // nextPage because we named it nextPage
  }
);

const paginatedData = [];
data.forEach((page) => {
  page.data.forEach((char) => {
    paginatedData.push(char);
  });
});

console.log(paginatedData) // The whole data
```

Update:

A better example using Rick and Morty API

```
async function getCharacters(page: number): Promise<Response> {
    const response = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=' + page)
    const characters = (await response.json())
    return characters;
}

const { ... } = useInfiniteQuery(['characters'], ({ pageParam = 1 }) => getCharacters(pageParam), {
  getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
    const nextUrl = lastPage.info.next
    if (nextUrl) {
      // Return next page number
      return Number(nextUrl.charAt(nextUrl.length - 1))
    }
    // Return false means no next page
    return false
  }
})
```

Answer (score 7):

The steps are:

> 1. Waiting for useInfiniteQuery to request the first group of data by default.
> 2. Returning the information for the next query in getNextPageParam.
> 3. Calling fetchNextPage function.

Reference https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/infinite-queries

Example 1 with rest api

```js
  const fetchProjects = ({ pageParam = 0 }) =>
     fetch('/api/projects?cursor=' + pageParam)
 
   const {
     data,
     isLoading,
     fetchNextPage,
     hasNextPage,
   } = useInfiniteQuery('projects', fetchProjects, {
     getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
       // lastPage signature depends on your api respond, below is a pseudocode
       if (lastPage.hasNextPage) {
         return lastPage.nextCursor;
       }
         return undefined;
     },
   })
```

Example 2 with graphql query (pseudocode)

```js
  const {
    data,
    fetchNextPage,
    isLoading,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(
    ['GetProjectsKeyQuery'],
    async ({ pageParam }) => {
      return graphqlClient.request(GetProjectsQuery, {
        isPublic: true, // some condition/variables if you have
        first: NBR_OF_ELEMENTS_TO_FETCH, // 10 to start with
        cursor: pageParam,
      });
    },
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
         // pseudocode, lastPage depends on your api respond
        if (lastPage.projects.pageInfo.hasNextPage) {
          return lastPage.projects.pageInfo.endCursor;
        }
        return undefined;
      },
    },
  );
```

react-query will create `data` which contains an array called `pages`. Every time you call api with the new cursor/page/offset it will add new page to pages. You can flatMap data, e.g:

`const projects = data.pages.flatMap((p) => p.projects.nodes)`

Call `fetchNextPage` somewhere in your code when you want to call api again for next batch, e.g:

```js
  const handleEndReached = () => {
    fetchNextPage();
  };
```

Graphql example query:

> add to your query `after: cursor`:

```
  query GetProjectsQuery($isPublic: Boolean, $first: Int, $cursor: Cursor) {
  projects(
    condition: {isPublic: $isPublic}
    first: $first
    after: $cursor
  ) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `getFetchMore()` has a `lastGroup` parameter. With this param, you have to check if your response (`lastGroup` parameter) has more data to fetch or not. In this case, I return a `page` variable, which will be the next page to fetch when you call `fetchMore()` and our `fetchPlanets()` async function gets this `page` variable as a parameter to `concat()` the new `api_url`.

I had a problem with the refetch on window focus because it had an issue to fetch the next group (`page`). So, I pass `refetchOnWindowFocus: false` in the options parameter.

```
const fetchPlanets = async (key, page = '1') => {
  const api_url = `https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page=${page}`;
  console.log(api_url);
  const res = await fetch(api_url);
  return res.json();
};

const Planets = () => {
  const { status, data, isFetching, isFetchingMore, fetchMore, canFetchMore } = useInfiniteQuery(
    ['planets'],
    fetchPlanets,
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      onSuccess: () => console.log('data fetch with no problemo!'),
      onError: () => console.log('data fetch error!'),
      getFetchMore: (lastGroup) => {
        lastGroup.page = lastGroup.next?.split('=')[1];
        return lastGroup.page;
      },
    },
  );

  console.log('data', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { useInfiniteQuery, useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

interface Post {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  userId: number;
}

interface PostQuery {
  pageSize: number;
}

const usePosts = (query: PostQuery) =>
  useInfiniteQuery<Post[], Error>({
    queryKey: ["posts", query],
    queryFn: ({ pageParam = 1 }) =>
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
          params: {
            _start: (pageParam - 1) * query.pageSize,
            _limit: query.pageSize,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => res.data),
    staleTime: 1 * 60 * 1000, // 1m
    keepPreviousData: true, // Keep data of current page instade of showing loading
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allPages) => {
      // 1->2
      return lastPage.length > 0 ? allPages.length + 1 : undefined;
    },
  });

export default usePosts;
```